# Create all combinations of length N from a given alphabet (2)

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, combinatorics

I implemented this challenge in Java before but performance was not the best so I decided to implement this in C++ to compare the two. The code works and performance is indeed much better than in the Java version. However I am unsure about the quality of this code.

I am still not overly familiar with modern C++ and would like to know if there is anything that I am doing awfully wrong.

*Challenge description:*

> You are given a number N and a string S. Print all of the possible ways to write a string of length N from the characters in string S, comma delimited in alphabetical order.
>
> The first argument will be the path to the input filename containing the test data. Each line in this file is a separate test case. Each line is in the format: N,S i.e. a positive integer, followed by a string (comma separated). E.g.
>
> Print all of the possible ways to write a string of length N from the characters in string S comma delimited in alphabetical order, with no duplicates.
>
> **Input sample:**
>
> ```
> 1,aa
> 2,ab
> 3,pop
> ```
>
> **Output sample:**
>
> ```
> a
> aa,ab,ba,bb
> ooo,oop,opo,opp,poo,pop,ppo,ppp
> ```

*Code:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

void generate_words(const std::vector<char> &alphabet, size_t &word_length, std::vector<std::string> &results)
{
    std::vector<size_t> index(word_length, 0);

    for (;;)
    {
        std::string word(index.size(), ' ');
        for (size_t i = 0; i < index.size(); ++i)
        {
            word[i] = alphabet[index[i]];
        }
        results.emplace_back(word);

        for (int i = index.size() - 1; ; --i)
        {
            if (i < 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            ++index[i];

            if (index[i] == alphabet.size())
            {
                index[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ifstream infile(argv[1], std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);

    std::string line;
    while (infile.good() && getline(infile, line))
    {
        size_t word_length = std::stoi(line.substr(0, line.find(',')));
        std::string letters = line.substr(line.find(',') + 1);

        std::vector<char> alphabet;
        for (const auto &it : letters)
        {
            alphabet.push_back(it);
        }
        std::sort(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());
        auto last = std::unique(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());
        alphabet.erase(last, alphabet.end());

        std::vector<std::string> results;
        generate_words(alphabet, word_length, results);

        std::ostringstream result_line;
        std::copy(results.begin(), results.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(result_line, ","));
        result_line << results.back();

        std::cout << result_line.str() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I thought adding a new version is fine as long as the original code stays untouched?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not, because if there is multiple answers it will be very confusing which answer reviews which version.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Just asking because I've seen it done before so I was under the assumption it was accepted behavior. Apologies.

Comment: We're trying to catch each time it happens, but we can't catch it all. If you see it, please flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **generate_words** code looks pretty good to me.

Actually, one minor thing - you can return the vector as opposed to passing out by reference. You won't get a performance hit (see [move semantics](https://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/move-semantics/)), and it'll make the function easier to use:

```
auto words = generate_words(letters, word_length);
```

Some minor observations about the code in **main**:

**1** - As a general rule, you should allocate a vector's memory up front if you know how many elements it will contain. This prevents reallocations from occurring when new elements are inserted into the vector. std::vector provides the [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) method for doing this:

```
std::vector<char> alphabet;
// allocate memory for at least letter.size() chars
alphabet.reserve(letters.size());
for (const auto &it : letters)
{
    // now you don't have to worry about reallocations happening
    // here
    alphabet.push_back(it);
}
```

See:

[What happens under the hood of vector::push_back memory wise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899973/what-happens-under-the-hood-of-vectorpush-back-memory-wise)

[std::vector push_back is bottleneck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006634/stdvector-push-back-is-bottleneck)

[vector::reserve example code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

In this case, you can skip the loop entirely by using std::vector's iterator constructor:

```
std::vector<char> alphabet(letters.begin(), letters.end());
```

**2** - If you're not using the variable 'letters' after it's been initialized, you could do your sort/unique operation in place:

```
std::sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());
letters.erase(std::unique(letters.begin(), letters.end()), letters.end());
```

and then pass letters to generate_words() (you'd have to change the first parameter to a string)

Answer (score 0):

So i think there are quite a lot of things to improve:

Use more function. Your code does a lot of stuff within a single function. Separate it into specialized functions, that do only one thing.

For example how to generate the alphabet. In your code you have this

```
    std::vector<char> alphabet;
    for (const auto &it : letters)
    {
        alphabet.push_back(it);
    }
    std::sort(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());
    auto last = std::unique(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());
    alphabet.erase(last, alphabet.end());
```

The first thing to note, is that this is highly inefficient, as you only want unique elements of your string. This kind of asks for a `std::set` Most importantly if you look in your favorite book you will find the following constructor:

```
set (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
   const key_compare& comp = key_compare(),
   const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

So you can pass it a suitable iterator and it constructs the set from its own. So how does that look like?

```
std::set<char> alphabet(letters.begin(), letters.end());
```

Thats it. No more searching sorting and finding multiple elements.

Now how to generate the words. Luckily there is `std::next algorithm`. However, life is hard and it does not work with a std::set, but, it works on strings, so after having again a look at my favorite book there is this little beauty:

```
template <class InputIterator>
string  (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Now we can construct the string from the set and permutate it

```
std::set<char> alphabet(letters.begin(), letters.end());
std::string word(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());
do {
    std::cout << word << ",";
} while ( std::next_permutation(word.begin(),word.end()) )
```

Comment: Which book are you refering to exactly? The permutation part looks nice but we are not actually doing a permutation here.